# how to include jquery library in angular 2 application

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-forms

How to include third party jQuery library in Angular 2 application?
How to include http://keith-wood.name/calendarspicker.html jQuery library in angular 2 application?

Comment: install package using npm install or you can add them in folder. to import it to project, add the js file path inside script object in  angular.cli file in you app root.

Answer (score 1):

1-In addition to install it through npm , try to include this line in your angular-cli.json file, inside apps->scripts key like this example:

```
{
  "apps": {
    "scripts": [
      "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
    ]
  }
}
```

2-Add this plugin to your webpack plugins in webpack.config.js (in module.exports):

```
   new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: "jquery",
    jQuery: "jquery"
   })
```

3- Then import it in the component you need to use it, for example: 
`import * as $ from 'jquery';`

Answer (score 1):

To add an external library to an Angular 2 app you download the files and place them in your assets folder (or any folder you may chose to add) `angular/src/assets/<your-library>` then add the path to the library in your `angular-cli.json` file.  If you upgrade to angular 6 the file is renamed `angular.json`

Here is an example of one of my `angular-cli.json` files

```
 "styles": [
    "../node_modules/materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.css",
    "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
    "styles.css"
  ],
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
    "../node_modules/jqueryui/jquery-ui.js",
    "../node_modules/materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.js",
    "./assets/RTCMultiConnection.min.js",
    "../node_modules/hammerjs/hammer.js",
    "./assets/popup.js"
  ],
```

It may, however be easier to add an "angular ready" alternative like [angular-bootstrap-calendar](https://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-calendar)